# Firebase Phone Number authentication in Chrome Extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

Is it possible?
I read a bit on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth but it mentions `OAuth redirect domains` all the time, not sure if chrome extension  domains are valid for this?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @noogui no, I'm still in phase of deciding if I'll go this route or not, that's why I asked here to get some insights, as I don't want to invest days into developing this only to come to a dead end because it's not possible to use

Comment: They are not since reCAPTCHA does not properly work in a chrome extension environment (it doesn't handle chrome extension domains)

Answer (score 1):

They don't work in a chrome extension, but you could render the reCAPTCHA verifier in a web page, get the verification ID and code and pass it to your chrome extension using something like `postMessage` and then sign in through your chrome extension as:

```
// You get verificationId from reCAPTCHA rendered on web page.
// You ask the user to provide the 6 digit code.
var cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred)
  .then(function(result) {
    // User signed in.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```